# ST_Union() takes too much time to process

Tags: postgis, raster

I have this query

`SELECT ST_Clip(rast, the_geom)FROM raster, polygons` that is very fast to process. `the_geom` has 50 geometries while `raster` is a 400x400 tiled 5-band raster layer (about 3GB in size).

While the above query works fine, `SELECT ST_Union(ST_Clip(rast, the_geom))
FROM raster, polygons` takes forever to process. I created spatial index `st_convexthull(rast)` while loading the raster to PostGIS. What would I have missed?

Thank you in advance.